# Is it possible to get the name of the file when opened with messagebox.askopenfile

Tags: file-io, tkinter, message, box

I am trying to open a file with `file = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir='./')`, but I need also to know the name of the file opened for other purposes. I know that if the user selects a file, file is not `None`, otherwise it's something like this:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/u/Desktop/e/config.py' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>
```

but `_io.TextIOWrapper` objects are not sub-scriptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By suggestion, I discovered that there exists another function similar to `messagebox.askopenfile`, `askopenfilename`, that instead of opening directly the file, returns just the name of the file. If we want also to open the file, we can open and read it manually:

```
file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='./')
if file_name != '':
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        string = ''
        for line in file:
            string += str(line)
        print(string)
```

Even if this is a good way, I'm still thinking that `tkinter` should have provided this functionality with `messagebox.askopenfile` directly.

Navigating trough the Python directory we can find the `filedialog.py` file, which contains the specifications of both functions, which are very similar:

```
def askopenfilename(**options):
    "Ask for a filename to open"

    return Open(**options).show()
```

`askopenfile`

```
def askopenfile(mode = "r", **options):
    "Ask for a filename to open, and returned the opened file"

    filename = Open(**options).show()
    if filename:
        return open(filename, mode)
    return None
```

As we can see, the first returns the result of the call to the `show` function, whereas the second returns an opened file.

Comment: Since askopenfile can return None instead of an opened file, `open askopenfile() as f:` might raise.